# Does controlling one sense ease controlling other senses?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, asuras

According to **Brihadaranyaka Upanishad**, senses drive towards the objects and the asuras will incarnate the sensual desires like wanting to eat something *tasty*, wanted to see something *beautiful* etc.

My question is, if we can control one sense, for example, restricting our self eating tasty food will ease the controlling of the other senses?

From my experience, I have found that, when I am able to control my mouth by stopping it to talk unnecessarily, I found it quite easy to control other senses. But I would like to know if this is explicitly stated in any Upanishads.

1. I feel, it is because the asuras in oneself will lose their power as each sense is controlled. Am I right?
2. Is there any particular order of controlling senses so that it will be easy for one to stop getting desires? For example, controlling mouth first, then tongue, nose, eyes, mind etc.
3. Is it also true that one who controls the senses are dearer to the Supreme being? Because, as restricting of desires is to make the God within oneself to win. So where the God wins, the Supreme being loves to be there?

Comment: Probably there is no hard and fast rule in this. But many people say that controlling breath is the first step for yogic discipline. By controlling the breath (pranayama) one gains control of other senses very very very easily! Also many people practice sitting in meditation (silence, control of mouth, pranayam, control of breath, closing your eyes, control of vision and sitting in a silent room (control of ears). So it all helps. one who controls senses are dear to Supreme Being. Dear-er is subjective and each person will claim he is dearer to Supreme Being.

Comment: @JavaTechnical, thank your a practical question. Much meaningful and useful for daily life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)I feel, it is because the asuras in oneself will lose their power as each sense is controlled. Am I right?**
Yes, you are right. once we control our senses we will gain real freedom from material modes. It is not true that letting the senses loose will satisfy them. Senses are like fire and the sense-pleasure is like ghee. The more you give the more it burns!

**(2)Is there any particular order of controlling senses so that it will be easy for one to stop getting desires? For example, controlling mouth first, then tongue, nose, eyes, mind etc.**

Not exactly but from practical experience of myself and seeing numerous others, chanting the holy names can easily help us to control our sense. According to the scriptures chanting of Hari's names is the yuga dharma. So first use your speech for taking His names and eat prasadam of Vishnu (offer whatever you cook with satvik ingredients to Him). Then the rest will be easy. If you eat food that ignites your passion and ignorance you will be overcome by lusty desires. One who controls the senses is called gosvami (master of senses). In regard to sense control Srila Rupa Gosvami states in [Upadesamrta](http://www.vedabase.com/en/noi/1):

> A sober person who can tolerate the urge to speak, the mind’s demands,
>   the actions of anger and the urges of the tongue, belly and genitals
>   is qualiﬁed to make disciples all over the world.

The ideal way to control all the senses is to try to use them in the service of Lord Krishna. One of the ideal example given in [Srimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/4/18-20) is that of Maharaja Ambarisa.

> Maharaja Ambarisha always engaged his **mind** in meditating upon the
>   lotus feet of Krishna, his **words** in describing the glories of the
>   Lord, his **hands** in cleansing the Lord's temple, and his **ears** in
>   hearing the words spoken by Krishna or about Krishna. He engaged his
>   **eyes** in seeing the Deity of Krishna, Krishna's temples and Krishna's
>   places like Mathura and Vrindavana, he engaged his **sense of touch** in
>   touching the bodies of the Lord's devotees, he engaged his sense of
>   **smell** in smelling the fragrance of tulasi offered to the Lord, and he
>   engaged his **tongue** in tasting the Lord's prasada. He engaged his **legs**
>   in walking to the holy places and temples of the Lord, his **head** in
>   bowing down before the Lord, and all his **desires** in serving the Lord,
>   twenty-four hours a day. Indeed, Maharaja Ambarisha never desired
>   anything for his own sense gratification. He engaged all his senses in
>   devotional service, in various engagements related to the Lord. This
>   is the way to increase attachment for the Lord and be completely free
>   from all material desires.

**(3)Is it also true that one who controls the senses are dearer to the Supreme being?**
Yes, Lord Krishna:

> [Bhagavad Gita 2.61](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/61) One who restrains his senses, keeping them under full control, and
>   ﬁxes his consciousness upon Me, is known as a man of steady
>   intelligence.
>
> [Bhagavad Gita 5.7](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/5/7) One who works in devotion, who is a pure soul, and who controls his
>   mind and senses is dear to everyone, and everyone is dear to him.
>   Though always working, such a man is never entangled.